# Creating subqueries

Tags: sql, report, cognos

I'm very new to [cognos](/questions/tagged/cognos), so need your help on the following:

One of the report input parameters is Order-By with options First name,Last name,Default.

I have a query item MainQuery which has these data items

- `EmployeeName`.
- `UserID`.
- `UserBadgeNo`.

The expression for the Employee Name data item is-

```
If ?order by? = 'Last name' then Emp.Employeelastname
else if ?order by?='First name' then Emp.Employeefirstname
else 'garbage'
```

The requirement is that there should be a new query item `FinalDisplayQuery` that should use the above sorted/ordered data, but display another column value.

So, the final output should be:

```
If Emp.employeelastname then display emp.empnewname
else if emp.employeefirst then display emp.empnextnewname
```

Can you help me figure out how I can go about doing this?Thx in advance for any help!

Comment: In the end do you want to have 4 columns or 3? I was not too clear what final result should be? 
For example if FirstName was chosen how should output look

Answer (score 1):

Create a new calculated query item (in Framework Manager or Report Studio) with that expression then drag it on to your page. Simple as that.